# Max value for rectangle's rounded corners in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I am trying to get a shape as shown in figure, a rectangle with corners completely round:
[image]

But it seems I can't get corners "rounder" than in this figure:

[image]

Why is that? there is a max value for `<corners android:radius="integer" />`?
Of course I could do that with a png, but I suppose using a shape is more efficient, so I would prefer that.

My code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_guest"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/text_button_guest"
    android:onClick="startGuestMode"
    android:text="@string/text_button_normal"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

rounded_rectangle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:radius="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: no,  there is no limit

Comment: To get as the first picture (semicircle corners on both left and right side), set the `corner size = half height`. In your case, **40dp**.

Comment: @pskink I know, yet the code above does not work; see below for my solution.

Comment: @Der Golem sorry, my typo, it was 40dp, I'll correct now. Anyway, it has the same behaviour for every value, say, above 25dp.

Comment: Work on margins and paddings... this `android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"` seems a bit exaggerated, to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I love when I scratch my head for hours, then I end up asking a question here, and then I find an answer by myself in less than 10 minutes :D

The solution is in my code below. You would think it should have the same behaviour, but apparently it has not. Probably another bug about rounded corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: Does this work on all layout densities? I remember having a similar drawable that was rendered differently on different densities(hdpi, xhdpi...)

Comment: I am developing for a specific device with API 15; I didn't tested on other devices, sorry. I think this should work for every density, though, if they did not correct this bug on later API versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="1500dp" />
</shape>
```

set the radius to maximum value, it will work in the all drawable, in this way you really don't need to depend on the `view height` value

Comment: This is exactly the code that I posted in my original question. It's not working with 40dp, how is it working with 1500dp?

Comment: Do you know why this works? There's nothing in the documentation saying this is how it behaves.
I'm concerned this could be a functionality a future version of Android might remove